# What is the best practice for outputing HTML from a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a web application that uses a combination of JSP and Java Servlets. I use the JSP for the main form and all servlets for outputing the results.

I have used various techiniques for outputing the HTML show below, but they all seem a little rough and I was wondering what the best practice for this is?

Example1:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("</head>");
...
```

Example 2:

```
out.println("<html> <head> </head> <body>") ...
```

Example 3:

```
String header = "<html> <head> </head> <body>";
output.println("<div> <p>" + result + "</p> </div>" );
```

Example 4:

```
Forward back to JSP for HTML and post result variable.
```

Comment: I've used Servlet in the pass to crunch data for report, and forwarded result to JSP for table report or to JSP (svg) for graphic report. Use JSP as visual formatting :)

Comment: Or use [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

Comment: @GriffeyDog so, you are saying to pass the variable back to a JSP and use that to output the results? What is the best method for that?

Comment: @Rhys cause that's what JSPs supposed to do - display dynamically generated HTML.

Comment: @Rhys You can use `request.setAttribute()` in your servlet to populate the data you want to access in the JSP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP is the view. Servlet is the controller. HTML is to be produced by the view. So, HTML belongs in JSP, not in Servlet.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Comment: Thanks for that, The wiki is very useful. Whats the best method for passing variables from Servlet to JSP? Is it request.setParameter Method? Your link says not to use `usebeans`

Comment: You're welcome. It's already shown in the Servlets wiki page. No, it's not `request.setParameter`. That method doesn't even [exist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) at all.

Comment: Sorry, I meant request.setAttribute